# iterate through a list of dates and calculate number of days in between each interval

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am sorry if this has already been asked, but I could not get a feasible solution to my problem. 
I would like to calculate the number of dates in between each interval of a list of dates which looks like

```
dates: 

['06/02/2008', '07/01/2008', '10/12/2007', '05/11/2007', '09/10/2007', '10/09/2007', 
'06/08/2007', '10/07/2007', '04/06/2007', '08/05/2007', '10/04/2007', '12/03/2007',
'05/02/2007', '08/01/2007', '11/12/2006', '06/11/2006', '10/10/2006', '05/09/2006',
 '07/08/2006', '10/07/2006', '05/06/2006', '08/05/2006', '10/04/2006', '13/03/2006',
 '06/02/2006', '09/01/2006', '05/12/2005', '07/11/2005', '11/10/2005', '06/09/2005',
'08/08/2005', '11/07/2005', '06/06/2005', '09/05/2005', '04/04/2005', '07/03/2005',
 '09/02/2005']
```

I have tried to do something like  `delta = dates - dates.shift(-1)` 
but with no success. The result I would like to get is a list called delta were I have a collection of the number of days in between each interval. For example the first diffference '06/02/2008' - '07/01/2008' = 30 days. Format of the date is 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then subtract all values without first with all values without last:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y')
delta =  dates[:-1] - dates[1:]
print (delta)
TimedeltaIndex(['30 days', '28 days', '35 days', '27 days', '29 days',
                '35 days', '27 days', '36 days', '27 days', '28 days',
                '29 days', '35 days', '28 days', '28 days', '35 days',
                '27 days', '35 days', '29 days', '28 days', '35 days',
                '28 days', '28 days', '28 days', '35 days', '28 days',
                '35 days', '28 days', '27 days', '35 days', '29 days',
                '28 days', '35 days', '28 days', '35 days', '28 days',
                '26 days'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

And if need integers add [`TimedeltaIndex.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.days.html):

```
delta =  (dates[:-1] - dates[1:]).days
print (delta)
Int64Index([30, 28, 35, 27, 29, 35, 27, 36, 27, 28, 29, 35, 28, 28, 35, 27, 35,
            29, 28, 35, 28, 28, 28, 35, 28, 35, 28, 27, 35, 29, 28, 35, 28, 35,
            28, 26],
           dtype='int64')
```

---

```
delta =  (dates[:-1] - dates[1:]).days.tolist()
print (delta)
[30, 28, 35, 27, 29, 35, 27, 36, 27, 28, 29, 35, 28, 28, 35, 27, 35, 29, 28, 
 35, 28, 28, 28, 35, 28, 35, 28, 27, 35, 29, 28, 35, 28, 35, 28, 26]
```